# How to get user response from messagebox or similar method - Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, popupwindow

In my WP8 app I need a user response. For example a window would popup and give 2 or 3 choices to the user (this options can be changed depending on my program, that can be 3 choices but another time 2). I try to use usercontrol and add listbox, in listbox I have my hyperlink which will be selected by user but I can't reach the hyperlink's tag in my main page because it is in the listbox

Here is my code

Usercontrolpage XAML

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstbox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HyperlinkButton Tag="{Binding text2}" Content="{Binding text}" x:Name="sure"  Tap="sure_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="sure_Click" />

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

  </ListBox>
```

This is c# codes from my main page(in this page user will click a button and usercontrol pops up).I should explain my codes more. In my app there is a book and every page has sounds to play. I put mp3 on internet and user can play them by clicking play button so in some pages I have 3 or 2 different mp3 file and I want to ask the user which one would they want to listen. So this is my play_click event, so if the page is 589 user have 2 mp3 file to listen I want to have a popup box and user will select one of them
The class at the bottom help me to bind my hyperlink with 2 different sources.

```
 Popup popup2 = new Popup();
        surepopup control2 = new surepopup();
        private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            string transferFileName="" ;

            if (a == 3) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Fatihah.mp3";
            if (a > 3 && a < 52) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Baqarah.mp3";
            if (a >= 52 && a < 79) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Imran.mp3";
            if (a >= 79 && a < 108) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Nisa'.mp3";
            if (a >= 108 && a < 130) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Ma'idah.mp3";
            if (a >= 130 && a < 153) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-An'am.mp3";
            if (a >= 153 && a < 179) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-A'raf.mp3";
            if (a >= 179 && a < 189) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Anfal.mp3";
            if (a >= 189 && a < 210) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Taubah.mp3";
            if (a >= 210 && a < 223) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Yunus.mp3";
            if (a >= 223 && a < 237) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Hood.mp3";
            if (a >= 237 && a < 251) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Yusuf.mp3";
            if (a >= 251 && a < 257) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ar-Ra'd.mp3";
            if (a >= 257 && a < 264) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ibrahim.mp3";
            if (a >= 264 && a < 269) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Hijr";
            if (a >= 269 && a < 284) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Nahl.mp3";
            if (a >= 284 && a < 295) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Isra.mp3";
            if (a >= 295 && a < 307) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Kahf.mp3";
            if (a >= 307 && a < 314) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Maryam.mp3";
            if (a >= 314 && a < 324) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ta-Ha.mp3";
            if (a >= 324 && a < 334) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Anbiya.mp3";
            if (a >= 334 && a < 344) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Hajj.mp3";
            if (a >= 344 && a < 352) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mu'minun.mp3";
            if (a >= 352 && a < 361) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Nur.mp3";
            if (a >= 361 && a < 369) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Furqan.mp3";
            if (a >= 369 && a < 379) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ash-Shu'ara'.mp3";
            if (a >= 379 && a < 387) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Naml.mp3";
            if (a >= 387 && a < 398) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Qasas.mp3";
            if (a >= 398 && a < 406) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-'Ankabut.mp3";
            if (a >= 406 && a < 413) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ar-Room.mp3";
            if (a >= 413 && a < 417) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Luqman.mp3";
            if (a >= 417 && a < 420) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/As-Sajdah.mp3";
            if (a >= 420 && a < 430) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Ahzab.mp3";
            if (a >= 430 && a < 436) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Saba'.mp3";
            if (a >= 436 && a < 442) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Fatir.mp3";
            if (a >= 442 && a < 448) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ya-Sin.mp3";
            if (a >= 448 && a < 455) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/As-Saffat.mp3";
            if (a >= 455 && a < 460) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Sad.mp3";
            if (a >= 460 && a < 469) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Az-Zumar.mp3";
            if (a >= 469 && a < 479) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ghafir.mp3";
            if (a >= 479 && a < 485) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Fussilat.mp3";
            if (a >= 485 && a < 491) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ash-Shu'ara'.mp3";
            if (a >= 491 && a < 498) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Az-Zukhruf.mp3";
            if (a >= 498 && a < 501) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ad-Dukhan.mp3";
            if (a >= 501 && a < 504) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Jathiya.mp3";
            if (a >= 504 && a < 509) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Ahqaf.mp3";
            if (a >= 509 && a < 513) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Muhammed.mp3";
            if (a >= 513 && a < 517) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Fath.mp3";
            if (a >= 517 && a < 520) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Hujurat.mp3";
            if (a >= 520 && a < 522) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Qaf.mp3";
            if (a >= 522 && a < 525) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Az-Zariyat.mp3";
            if (a >= 525 && a < 528) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Tur.mp3";
            if (a >= 528 && a < 530) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Najm.mp3";
            if (a >= 530 && a < 533) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Qamar.mp3";
            if (a >= 533 && a < 536) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Ar-Rahman.mp3";
            if (a >= 536 && a < 539) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Waqi'ah.mp3";
            if (a >= 539 && a < 544) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Hadid.mp3";
            if (a >= 544 && a < 547) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mujadilah.mp3";
            if (a >= 547 && a < 551) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Hashr.mp3";
            if (a >= 551 && a < 553) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mumtahinah.mp3";
            if (a >= 553 && a < 555) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/As-Saff.mp3";
            if (a >= 555 && a < 556) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Jumu'ah.mp3";
            if (a >= 556 && a < 558) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Munafiqun.mp3";
            if (a >= 558 && a < 560) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Taghabun.mp3";
            if (a >= 560 && a < 562) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Talaq.mp3";
            if (a >= 562 && a < 564) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Tahrim.mp3";
            if (a >= 564 && a < 566) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mulk.mp3";
            if (a >= 566 && a < 568) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Qalam.mp3";
            if (a >= 568 && a < 570) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Haqqah.mp3";
            if (a >= 570 && a < 572) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Ma'arij.mp3";
            if (a >= 572 && a < 574) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Nooh.mp3";
            if (a >= 574 && a < 576) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Jinn.mp3";
            if (a >= 576 && a < 577) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Muzzamil.mp3";
            if (a >= 577 && a < 579) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Muddaththir.mp3";
            if (a >= 579 && a < 580) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Qiyamah.mp3";
            if (a >= 580 && a < 582) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Insan.mp3";
            if (a >= 582 && a < 584) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mursalat.mp3";
            if (a >= 584 && a < 585) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/An-Naba'.mp3";
            if (a >= 585 && a < 587) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/AN-Nazi'at.mp3";
            if (a >= 587 && a < 588) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/'Abasa.mp3";
            //2 sure var
            if (a >= 588 && a < 589) transferFileName = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/At-Takwir.mp3";
            if (a >= 589 && a < 591) 
            {
                List<string> TextData = new List<string> 
                { 
                  "Al-Infitar.mp3",  
                  "Al-Mutaffifin.mp3",  

                };
            List<string> mp3link = new List<string> 
                { 
                    "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Infitar.mp3",  
                  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/Al-Mutaffifin.mp3",  

                };
                ObservableCollection<URLListBoxCalss> obj = new ObservableCollection<URLListBoxCalss>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    obj.Add(new URLListBoxCalss(TextData[i],mp3link[i]));
                }
                control2.lstbox.ItemsSource = obj;
                popup2.Child = control2;
                popup2.IsOpen = true;
```

Here I want to get hyperlinks tag to my transferfilename(string) but it seems I can't reach hyperlink because it is in listbox

```
                 transferFileName = ?;



            }
            if (a >= 591 && a < 592) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 592 && a < 593) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 593 && a < 594) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 594 && a < 595) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 595 && a < 596) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 596 && a < 597) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 597 && a < 598) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 598 && a < 599) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 599 && a < 600) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 600 && a < 601) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 601 && a < 602) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 602 && a < 603) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 603 && a < 604) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 604 && a < 605) transferFileName = "";
            if (a >= 605 && a < 606) transferFileName = "";


            string fileName = transferFileName.Substring(transferFileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            try
            {
                using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (isf.FileExists(fileName))
                    {
                        using (var isoStream = isf.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            mediaSound.Stop();
                            mediaSound.SetSource(isoStream);

                            mediaSound.Position = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                            kuranslider.Maximum = mediaSound.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
                            kuranslider.Minimum = 0;

                            mediaSound.Volume = 20;
                            mediaSound.Play();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("file does not exist you should first download the file ");
            }
            if (transferFileName.Equals("")) 
                MessageBox.Show("file does not exist you should first download the file");
        }
        public class URLListBoxCalss
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string text2 { get; set; }


            public URLListBoxCalss() { }

            public URLListBoxCalss(string text,string text2)
            {
                this.text = text;
                this.text2 = text2;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Code tip #1: Set `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/` as constant in your code and combine/concatenate it with `Al-Insan.mp3` in the IF-statement.
Code tip #2: Replace your IF-block with a Switch-statement and use the fall-thought method.

Comment: Tip #3 don't paste huge amounts of irrelevant code on SO, like the tens of "if" statements